# identify the encoding format of special characters

Tags: windows, excel, csv, text, character-encoding

Assume I have a csv file including sth like

```
abcón
```

I used the `Text import wizard` of Excel to import it. The wizard asks to specify the font encoding information. How can I know exactly the encoding format for the special character included in the above.

Comment: You have to ask whomever created the file.  Or make a guess at it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246956/notepad-can-recognize-encoding), you can't determine the encoding of a file to 100%.

In your case you could open the file in e.g. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and then look up the encoding Notepad++ has used for the file (Menu "Encoding" in the Menubar). Then use this encoding for the import wizard.