# Unmappable character for encoding

Tags: java, encoding, ant, utf-8, cp1252

I'm trying to build my java project using ANT.

While running ant command i get the following error:

```
error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
```

I have also refrered to previous posts related to this same very query on here and as suggested added 'encoding' attribute to javac property as

```
<javac .....  encoding="UTF-8"> .... </javac>
```

which in turn gives me the following error:-

```
error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

I cannot make any changes to my code so i was hoping if there was any other solution to this.

Comment: Well what encoding *is* your file in? Can you give an example of the bytes and the corresponding characters you expect to be represented?

Answer (score 0):

Using a text editor like Notepad++, you can find out the encoding of the java code your are trying to compile, and pass the encoding to the ant compiler.

This thread maybe useful : [Notepad++ can recognize encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246956/notepad-can-recognize-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the encoding of your project sources, because likely contain both CP1252 and UTF-8 files, so you need to fix it. The error message should tell you the filename and the position where the illegal sequence occurred. You should then open the file with your usual editor (that hopefully stores the encoding somewhere) and transcode it to the target encoding.

In the case of the first error message consider that CP1252 is a fixed length, single byte encoding, and from [this CP1252 table](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) it seems only a few bytes don't represent any character:

```
0x81
0x8D
0x90
0x9D
```

You can open the file with a hex editor and identify the first occurrence of one of these bytes to help you guess the charset if it's neither CP1252 nor UTF8 and you absolutely can't figure out what it is.