# Opening .dat file UnicodeDecodeError: invalid start byte

Tags: python, file, binary

I am using Python to convert a .dat file (which you can find [here](https://www.data.jma.go.jp/svd/eqev/data/bulletin/data/shindo/i2019.zip)) to csv in order for me to use it later in numpy or csv reader.

```py
import csv

# read flash.dat to a list of lists
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./i2019.dat").readlines()]

# write it as a new CSV file
with open("./i2019.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(datContent)
```

But this results in an error message of

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 68: invalid start byte

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your dat file uses [`Shift JIS`(Japanese) encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS).
So you can pass `shift_jis` as the `encoding` argument to the `open` function.

```
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./i2019.dat", encoding='shift_jis').readlines()]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I tried your code but it outputs a different message: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 760-761: illegal encoding". Would this because maybe the file that I am working with has formatting issues?

Comment: Thank you so much. That outputted somthing! Sorry but, it outputs these weird string characters that are not readable... for example: "㔸娠〰㘰′ぐ\u3130ぐ\u3130ぐ\u3130ぐ\u3130ぐ\u3130"... What do you suggest that I do? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @StevenOh I think your file uses `shift_jis` encoding. I have updated my answer can you try again?

Comment: Wow! That worked out perfectly. Thank you so much. Would it be possible for you to tell me how you were able to figure out the encoding format??

Comment: @StevenOh If you are using windows and have notepad ++ installed, [it can autodetect the encoding of the file. But note that it may not be accurate in all cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247144/6699447)